# Change numbers in the Number column to be consecutive from 0 for an mdadm RAID array

Tags: mdadm

I have a RAID 1 array:

```
# mdadm --detail /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Thu Oct 18 21:52:43 2012
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 1048564 (1024.16 MiB 1073.73 MB)
  Used Dev Size : 1048564 (1024.16 MiB 1073.73 MB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 3
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Fri Oct 19 16:25:32 2012
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 3
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 1

           Name : cow:0  (local to host cow)
           UUID : 9e691db1:f8fcc7d8:f56d9c11:1c202693
         Events : 98

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       2       8        2        0      active sync   /dev/sda2
       3       8       18        1      active sync   /dev/sdb2

       4       8       34        -      spare   /dev/sdc2
```

Is it possible to change the numbers in the `Number` column to 0, 1, 2 instead of 2, 3, 4? They were 0, 1, 2 until I messed around a bit with the array, removing and adding devices.

Comment: If you recreate the array, that'll do it. Or maybe stop and start, not sure. I confess I've never cared, and I'm not sure why anyone should...

Comment: Ohh, someone who is as anal-retentive as me! Would also like to know the answer to this.

Comment: @Magnus: I think a lot of "us" are that way. By the way, if you find value in the question, there is a link for that. ;-)

Comment: @derobert: I'm just slightly OCD'ing over it. ;-) And maybe it's a learning experience too. Stop and start didn't do it.

Answer (score 1):

These numbers are ***permanent*** device identifiers that are stored in the *superblock* of the RAID array devices ([field "dev_number" in the "This-Component-Device" section](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_superblock_formats#Section:_This-Component-Device_Information_area)) and cannot be changed.

However, you can re-create the ***clean*** array using the same devices which will generate a new superblock with new device identifiers.

---

*This operation should not affect any data stored on the RAID array, only the RAID metadata (superblock).*

---

**1**. Backup your data - *Better safe than sorry* - **Do this at your own risk**

```
# Retrieve [/dev/md0] metadata version
METADATAVER=`cat /sys/block/md0/md/metadata_version`
```

**2**. Stop the RAID array

```
mdadm --stop /dev/md0
```

**3**. Re-create the RAID array, *assumed as clean*, **with the same metadata version**

```
mdadm --create /dev/md0 --assume-clean --metadata=$METADATAVER --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sda2 /dev/sdb2

    mdadm: /dev/sda2 appears to be part of a raid array:
          level=raid1 devices=2 ctime=Sun Mar 11 11:11:11 2021
    mdadm: /dev/sdb2 appears to be part of a raid array:
          level=raid1 devices=2 ctime=Sun Mar 11 11:11:11 2021
    Continue creating array? y
    mdadm: array /dev/md0 started.
```

**4**. Re-add the spare device to the RAID array

```
mdadm --add /dev/md0 /dev/sdc2
```

**5**. Enjoy your OCD free device numbers

```
mdadm --detail /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Mon Mar 13 13:13:13 2023
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 1048564 (1024.16 MiB 1073.73 MB)
     Used Dev Size : 1048564 (1024.16 MiB 1073.73 MB)
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 3
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

       Update Time : Mon Mar 13 13:13:13 2023
             State : clean 
    Active Devices : 2
   Working Devices : 3
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 1

Consistency Policy : resync

              Name : cow:0  (local to host cow)
              UUID : 9e691db1:f8fcc7d8:f56d9c11:1c202693
            Events : 3

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       7        1        0      active sync   /dev/sda2
       1       7        2        1      active sync   /dev/sdb2

       2       7        3        -      spare   /dev/sdc2
```

---

*This answer is inspired from "[Converting between superblock versions](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_superblock_formats#Converting_between_superblock_versions)" by Neil Brown, originally posted to the linux-raid mailing list.*

---